# How can I avoid user being prompted a second time for Google account selection?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm developing and Android app with Google Play Games Services and I've followed the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#step_2_set_up_the_game_in_the_dev_console) by importing the BaseGameUtils as a module into my IntelliJ project. This is now working fine except that whenever I open an activity which inherits `BaseGameActivity` and call `beginUserInitiatedSignIn()`, the user is prompted to select which Google account to connect with (if more than one is present at the phone). Now this would be fine if it weren't for the fact that in my app, the user is already authed through Google Play Services [using OAuth2](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html) ([GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html)/[AccountPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.html)). It's given which account he/she wants to use - one shouldn't need to ask again.

Is there anyway I can modifiy `BaseGameActivity.java` or `GameHelper.java` so that the user is not prompted again? And/or do i need to alter how I log in with OAuth2?

I've tried adding the four scopes PLUS_PROFILE, PLUS_LOGIN, GAMES and APP_STATE to my OAuth login routine, but the AccountPicker-popup sill appears in my activity inheriting from BaseGameActivity.

*Update*: Logcat-log

```
07-23 11:45:25.275: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0
07-23 11:45:25.275: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.
07-23 11:45:25.285: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): Connecting GamesClient.
07-23 11:45:25.295: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): onStart.
07-23 11:45:25.295: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): onStart: connecting clients.
07-23 11:45:25.295: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): Connecting GamesClient.
07-23 11:45:25.395: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): onConnectionFailed: result 4
07-23 11:45:25.395: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): onConnectionFailed: since user initiated sign-in, trying to resolve problem.
07-23 11:45:25.395: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{4190b780: android.os.BinderProxy@4190a780}}
07-23 11:45:25.395: DEBUG/CSDN-GMS(22315): result has resolution. Starting it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to login with OAuth2 first, or could you sign into Google Games first? If you can get away with signing into Google Games first, you could maybe use `GamesClient.getCurrentAccountName()`. From https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#getCurrentAccountName() :

> Get the name of the currently selected account. This is the account the user has chosen to use for Google Play Games.

Then you could feed that account selection into OAuth2 authentication.

Comment: This sounds like a promising approach. "AccountName" in this context is the GMail address? (wasn't clear from the docs)

Comment: That's a good question. I too had the same question. I haven't tried it yet personally; I'm still in the research phase to see what it would take to update my app to use Google Play Games Services. This is currently how I hope to solve the same problem you're facing (and how I stumbled across your post).

Comment: Finally got around to testing this: it works. AccountName is the gmail-address, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at / post a logcat trace. This is what a succesful trace looks like when the user is not signed on :

```
07-04 10:21:54.511: D/ian_(1781): MultiTab3 beginUserInitiatedSignIn
07-04 10:21:54.531: D/ian_(1781): isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0
07-04 10:21:54.531: D/ian_(1781): beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.
07-04 10:21:54.611: D/ian_(1781): resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: C      onnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{40f3ed38: android.os.BinderProxy@40ee3de0}}
07-04 10:21:54.611: D/ian_(1781): result has resolution. Starting it.
07-04 10:21:54.621: D/ian_(1781): startResolutionForResult - this may be prob ?
07-04 10:23:29.480: D/ian_(1781): MultiPlayer onActivityResult called9001-1null
07-04 10:23:29.520: D/ian_(1781): MultiPlayer passing onActivityResult to MultiTab3 Req/Resp/Data=9001-1null
07-04 10:23:29.520: D/ian_(1781): MultiTab3 onActivityResult - passing through to GameHelper ...9001-1null
07-04 10:23:29.520: D/ian_(1781): onActivityResult, req 9001 response -1
07-04 10:23:29.520: D/ian_(1781): responseCode == RESULT_OK. So connecting.
07-04 10:23:30.130: D/ian_(1781): onConnected: connected! client=1
07-04 10:23:30.130: D/ian_(1781): All clients now connected. Sign-in successful.
07-04 10:23:30.130: D/ian_(1781): All requested clients connected. Sign-in succeeded!
```

beginUserInitiatedSignIn only launches the Google "choose an account" dialog (result has resolution. Starting it) if the user is not signed in (or if there was some problem). You will see that in my example the reason this happened was SIGN_IN_REQUIRED.

Look at your logcat and see what the message says. If necessary you can get a more detailed trace.

N.B. If the user is signed in then the path is shorter and simpler and the "choose an account" dialog is not displayed - perhaps it would be a good idea to try it out on one of the sample apps first ?

Comment: Updated with my logcat. Basically the same as yours. I don't know if there is any way I can intercept the "startResolutionForResult "..

Comment: I think you'd be better off trying to figure out why you are getting mConnectionResult != null - it looks like your sign-in isn't valid. However, if you think it is, you could just try removing resolveConnectionResult();

Comment: Well I am not authorized to Google+, only Google accounts, so I'm not surprised it fails. I merely want to tell the GamesClient that user X is authed with Google account Y, so please use account Y also for the Game Service authorization (Google+). Removing reoslveConnectionResult() will not help.

Comment: Hey @IanB, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151