# How do you combine OAuth2 with Google Play Games Services login?

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have an app where I want to satisfy these three conditions:

1. It must provide [OAuth2-login](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) for all users.
2. It must provide an option to log in to [Google Play Games Services](https://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/games.html&ei=-4rvUZLVEZL34QTZgoAQ&usg=AFQjCNFYAWFLrOZzvK-e1lJMZvQyYiqyxw&sig2=-GxMtKFnh8rkw85wTUu_qw&bvm=bv.49641647,d.bGE)
3. The application must enforce the same gmail-account to be used in both cases

Before Google Play Games Services was released, I had already implemented OAuth2-login for my app. I tried to patch the existing app by implementing a new Activity for the Games Service Login, following the [sample app implementation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart) template. This made it impossible for me to satisfy condition #3 because it would prompt for the GMail-account to use (if multiple present) a second time. See [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701504/how-can-i-avoid-user-being-prompted-a-second-time-for-google-account-selection).

So I have a couple of question in relation to this:

1. Have anyone done this, or is there a guide on how to to this?
2. Is OAuth2-login a different thing from Google Play Games Services Login?
3. Is Google Play Services login a different thing from G+ login?
4. If I go with Google Play Games Services login off the bat and toss the OAuth2-login, will that solve the problem?
5. If yes to #1, how do I do it and integrate it with my back-end (Today I verify the token at the back-end)?

I realize this is a series of questions and as such does not fit the SO-model perfectly, but I don't know where else to ask.